# Ошибка The method ... is undefined for the type new ...{}

Tags: java

```
JList jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jList1.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            Vector v = makeVectorData(strings);

            public int getSize() {
                return v.size();
            }

            public Object getElementAt(int i) {
                return v.get(i);
            }
        });
        jList1.setCellRenderer(new JlistRenderer());
        jList1.addFocusListener(new JListFocusListener(jList1));

public class JlistRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
            JSeparator separator;
            final String SEPARATOR = "SEPARATOR";
            public JlistRenderer() {
              setOpaque(true);
              setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
              separator = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
            }
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
              String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
              if (SEPARATOR.equals(str)) {
                return separator;
              }
              if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
              } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
              }
              setFont(list.getFont());
              setText(str);
              return this;
            }
        }

public class JListFocusListener implements FocusListener {
             JList list;
            Object currentItem;
            final String SEPARATOR = "SEPARATOR";
            JListFocusListener(JList list) {
              this.list= list;
              list.setSelectedIndex(0);
              currentItem = list.getSelectedValue();
            }
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
              String tempItem = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
              if (SEPARATOR.equals(tempItem)) {
                list.setSelectedValue(currentItem,true);
              } else {
                currentItem = tempItem;
              }
            }
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

            }
        }
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку

> The method makeVectorData(String[]) is undefined for the type new AbstractListModel(){}

Помогите исправить!

Comment: Метода makeVectorData - нет в классе AbstractListModel. Откуда вы его берете из вашего кода не понятно.

Comment: Я делаю вот по этому: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786907/java-list-with-line-separation

Comment: Видимо вам надо самим реализовать этот метод. PS. вы хоть пытались понять что там ответили? или просто скопировали и ожидаете чуда?

Comment: Пытался разобраться, но я думал этот метод есть в классе

Comment: @NowenUI чтобы узнать, что есть в классе, используйте официальную документацию. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что в классе `AbstractListModel`, который вы наследуете, нет метода `makeVectorData(strings)`. Вам нужно добавить реализацию метода в анонимный класс, например, вот так:

```
jList1.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            Vector v = makeVectorData(strings);

            public int getSize() {
                return v.size();
            }

            public Object getElementAt(int i) {
                return v.get(i);
            }

            private Vector<String> makeVectorData(String[][] strings) {
                Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
                //код метода
                return data;
            }
        });
```

Или отказаться от использования анонимного класса и вынести это в отдельный класс (возможно, внутренний).